# Drilldown line highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, drilldown

I am working on line chart. I am sending two sets of data. Both are date,value pair. One set is of average and another is for daily readings. I need to make it drill down so that when I click on the average it will take me to all the readings of the day. The data is dynamic. Can anyone please help me how to approach with this ?

Comment: Have you checked the existing demos? http://www.highcharts.com/demo Also, highmaps have demos on drill down.

Comment: I have seen them. But they are all with the static data

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130503/drill-down-function-in-highcharts-in-case-of-line-charts

Comment: @Sebastian I looked at that one but that is for static data. I need some example for dynamic array of data..I have no clue at all how to begin .

Comment: So on click at point, you would like to load data dynamically?

Comment: My click points will be dynamic and yes the data needs to be loaded dynamically too.